# Firebase on android automatically finish my app without errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im traying to create a application what salve some data in firebase, but when i try run my app, the app automatically finish, because en main actyvity call to firebase database`

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

in this moment, the app close, without errors, the consolo puts Builds Succesful, i do not know what causes it.

This is my project if you want check
https://mega.nz/#!9JNV1DTI!mnE2aw8AO1Amfx0FmLtOTsRZydaaA40fpLxcES2WWj4

Comment: So if you comment out this line and not use it, your app does not crash? Do you see any Log output for your app?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero, PID: 28136
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero/com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: Well looks like you *do* have an error. Are you absolutely sure you're calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` *before* attempting to get a reference in Firebase as the error message says?